# How to iterate over a df column with the condition of "a slice of a string" .isnumeric()

Tags: python, pandas, loops, slice, series

In one line, I want to get the rows of a df in which one column starts with a three digit number. Obviously it can be done with different methods (such as string slicing, or with a for loop). I wanted to do it by using *[pandas.Series.str.isnumeric]*[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html). Surprisingly I got an "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'".

Here is the necessary part of the df:

```
>>> df.loc[df.title.str[0:3]=="123"].title
>>> 0       123Besiktas Modern Eşyalı 4+1 Kiralık Daire (129)
    90      123Besiktas Selenium Panorama Yeni Eşyalı 1+1 ...
    8542    123Besiktas Büyükhanlı Eşyalı Boğaz Manzaralı ...
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Here is the code and error:

```
>>> df.loc[[df.title.str[0:3]].isnumeric()]
>>> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-74a315c862f9> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[[df.title.str[0:3]].isnumeric()]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) says:
*Series.str.isnumeric(self)* is equivalent to running the Python string method *str.isnumeric()* for each element of the Series/Index. If a string has zero characters, False is returned for that check.

Of course the Python *str.isnumeric()* method allows slicing:

```
>>>w = "123Besiktas"
...w[0:3].isnumeric()
>>>True
```

But *pandas.Series.str.isnumeric()* does not allow slicing!
In fact it is not only about *.isnumeric()* but also all *.isXXX()* methods.

So, my question is:
Is this something that Pandas developers should take care of, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an extra set of square braces? What happens if you try `df.loc[df.title.str[0:3].isnumeric()]`?

Comment: "List" changed to "Series" as expected but same result: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Comment: df.loc[df.title.str[0:3].str.isnumeric()] should be the right way. The str.isnumeric method should follow immediately after the string. df.title.str[:3].str.isnumeric

Comment: Yes [@sammywemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175713/sammywemmy). It worked. But why (if you have time)?

Comment: @Abd_bgc, that is the function. str.isnumeric(). same as str.split() or str.contains(). I guess it is a design decision by the Pandas team.